# Crear clase dinámicamente con c#

Tags: c#

Necesito crear una clase dinámica puesto que estoy recibiendo un objeto dinámico.  Actualmente hago algo como esto:

```
dynamic clase=new ExpandoObject();

clase.Prop1="";clase.Prop2=1;
```

Sin embargo tengo entendido que el uso de `Class <T>`  es mucho mejor para mejorar el performance. Es posible hacer algo como lo que hice con dynamic pero con `Class<T>` ?? Si supiera cuales son las propiedades de la clase creo que si podría pero como necesito crear las propiedades en tiempo de ejecución no se como podría hacerlo con `Class<T>`

Comment: estas usando framework o .net core ahora si estas listando las propiedades y asignando valores ya no es dinamico. Agrega mas informacion a tu duda.

Answer (score 1):

**El uso de `class<T>` es para reutilizar una clase con metodo que reciben el mismo Tipo instanciado. ejemplo ->**

Creo la clase que recibe T y sus metodos tambien reciben T

```
 public class DatosMovil <T>
 {
    public async Task<List<T>> GetAll(string url)
    {
        List<T> resultado = new List<T>();
        Uri uri = new Uri(url);

        httpResponse = await GetHttpResponse(uri, HttpMethod.Get);
        if (httpResponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            content = httpResponse.Content;
            var json = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            resultado = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json);

        }
        return resultado;
    }
 }
```

**Entonces si necesitas llamar a esta clase con cualquier tipo, podrias llamarlo con la clase Pais**

```
DatosMovil<Pais> datosMovil;

public async void RellenarGrid()
{
  datosMovil= new DatosMovil<Pais>();
  List<Pais> listado =  await datosMovil.GetAll(uri);
}
```

**o podes llamarlo con la clase Continente.**

```
DatosMovil2<Continentes> datosMovil;

public async void RellenarGrid()
{
  datosMovil= new DatosMovil<Continentes>();
  List<Continentes> listado =  await datosMovil2.GetAll(uri);
}
```

De esta manera reutilizas codigo y metodos pasandole la clase que necesitas, que algun servicio web te devuelve.

Answer (score 0):

Verifica [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362532/get-the-type-for-a-object-declared-dynamic) que es similar

```
// Basicamente obtienes un tipo concreto
Type unknown = ((ObjectHandle)tmp).Unwrap().GetType();
// Que puedes instanciar dinamicamente despues
var miObj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Foo));
```